# Keep Æ, Ø and Å in data, regex

Tags: python, regex

This one goes out to the regex experts: How would I be able to remove symbols without removing Æ, Ø and Å (which are important letters in the Danish alphabet)?
Here is what I got that removes symbols but also Ææ, Øø and Åå:

```
import re

df_all.text = df_all.apply(lambda row: " ".join(re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", row.text).split()), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", row.text)
```

will replace every sequence that doesn't (`^`) match the character class `a-zA-Z` with a single space.

Thus, add the letters you want to keep to the character class.

```
[^a-zA-ZÆæØøÅå]+
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is still incomplete under Unicode normalization. If your regex contains the single glyph å ([U+00E5](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e5/index.htm)) it will not match the decomposed sequence a + [COMBINING RING ABOVE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030a/index.htm), and vice versa (and of course, similarly for upper case)